# How to hide and unhide rows based on a cell value?

Tags: excel, vba

I have an Excel spreadsheet that has tabs with questions to fill out.

I counted the columns to make sure I had the right one and looped through the code using the debugger step by step to see the values it read out. The values all appeared to be in order.

The contents are (mostly) confidential and it is too much to empty so I will attempt to show you this way:

This shows the values. I am working with the "basis" column. The letter of the corresponding column is Y.
[image: This shows the values. I am working with the "basis" column. The letter of the corresponding column is Y]

I want to hide or show questions based on the value of the cell. 0 means hide and 1 means show.

I have found that the code hides and unhides at will.

```
Sub CheckRoleQuestionsSimplified()

For Each ws In ThisWorkbook.Worksheets

    If ws.Name = "Cockpit" Or ws.Name = "I-CBO" Or ws.Name = "config" Or ws.Name = "BegeleidingsFormulier" Or ws.Name = "Inhoudsopgave" Or ws.Name = "Saldibalans" Then
        ' Sla deze over, doe niks
    Else
        Worksheets(ws.Name).Activate
    End If

Next ws

beginRow = 10
endRow = 46
checkCol = 25

Do While rowNum < endRow
    If Cells(rowNum, checkCol).Value = 0 Then
        Cells(rowNum, checkCol).EntireRow.Hidden = True
    Else
        If Cells(rowNum, checkCol).Value = 1 Then
            Cells(rowNum, checkCol).EntireRow.Hidden = False
        End If
    End If
Next rowNum
End Sub
```

Comment: Please post your code as text, not as image.

Comment: Never rely on which sheet is active in your code. Use explicit references instead or confusing things like this happen. You are partially there already tho... instead of `Cells` use `ws.Cells`

Answer (score 1):

Use With statement. and use isEmpty function.

```
Sub CheckRoleQuestionSimplified()
    Dim Ws As Worksheet
    Dim Target As Range
    Dim rowNum As Integer, endRow As Integer, checkCol As Integer
    For Each Ws In ThisWorkbook.Worksheets
        Select Case Ws.Name
        Case "Cockpit", "I-CBO", "config"
        Case Else
            With Ws
                beginRow = 10
                endRow = 46
                checkCol = 25
                For rowNum = beginRow To endRow
                    Set Target = .Cells(rowNum, checkCol)
                    Target.EntireRow.Hidden = False
                    If Not IsEmpty(Target) Then '<~~ check Empty
                        If Target.Value = 0 Then
                            Target.EntireRow.Hidden = True
                        Else
                            If Target.Value = 1 Then
                                Target.EntireRow.Hidden = False
                            End If
                        End If
                    End If
                Next rowNum
            End With
        End Select
    Next Ws
End Sub
```

Comment: Your answer appears to be working, however it also seems to hide empty rows. Where should I look to find out how to fix that? I need the empty rows to make the sheet workable. Maybe this is something on my end but it seemed odd.

Edit: I mean empty rows as in rows with no value at all. The rows with 0 in the defined column need to be hidden **only**

Comment: @Bastiaan, Didn't you try to hide the entire row? The gist of the question is not clear.

Comment: You can replace the `If-ElseIf` construct in the loop with one statement: `Target.EntireRow.Hidden  = (Target.Value = "0")`. Note the quotes around the `0`: If you compare an empty cell with the numeric value 0, it will be `True` (and therefore the row will be hidden). If you compare an empty cell with the string `"0"`, it will be `False` (and the row will be displayed)

Comment: @Bastiaan, I modified my answer. use isempty function.

Comment: @Dy.Lee Yes I did try (and was planning on) hiding the entire row, you are correct. But it hid empty rows too which were the rows I needed for the signature and all.

Comment: So, your solution works fine, except I am left with a bunch of signature rows being shown now. I was considering seeing if I could subtract 1 from the target row and hide those alongside the row that is supposed to be hidden to counter this.

However, I am unsure if it is as simple as "Target -1.EntireRow.Hidden = True"

Answer (score 0):

This should work:

```
Dim ws As Worksheet
Dim beginRow As Long, endRow As Long, checkCol As Long

beginRow = 10
endRow = 46
checkCol = 25
For Each ws In ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets
    If ws.Name = "Cockpit" Or ws.Name = "I-CBO" Or ws.Name = "config" Or ws.Name = "BegeleidingsFormulier" Or ws.Name = "Inhoudsopgave" Or ws.Name = "Saldibalans" Then
        ' do nothing
    Else
        For rowNum = beginRow To endRow Step 2
            With ws.Cells(rowNum, checkCol)
                .Resize(2, 1).EntireRow.Hidden = .Value = 0
            End With
        Next rowNum
    End If
Next ws
```

This process relies upon the `0` or `1` **only** being in even numbered rows, as per your screenshot.

Note: if you want *all* empty rows hidden, use the following loop instead:

```
        For rowNum = beginRow To endRow
            With ws.Cells(rowNum, checkCol)
                .EntireRow.Hidden = .Value = 0
            End With
        Next rowNum
```